# How to install gtk-recordmydesktop?

Tags: apt, python, dependencies, gtk

I've upgraded Linux to the newest version recently, and re-installed recordmydesktop, but I want to install gtk-recordmydesktop, the one that allows you to pause it and select what part of the screen you want to record. How do I install it?

When I tried to use this command:
`apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./gtk-recordmydesktop_0.3.8-4.1ubuntu1_all.deb`

It gave this error:

````
 gtk-recordmydesktop : Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
                       Recommends: python-appindicator but it is not installable
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
               Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```
````

I have those versions of python, though. How do I fix this and download gtk-recordmydesktop?
(Don't suggest another screen recorder.)

Comment: In modern Ubuntu, the vast majority of Python 2 packages were removed.  As a result, software that depends entirely on Python 2 is unlikely supported.  As a result of you upgrading to the newest version, GTK2 is deprecated, and the corresponding python 2 dependencies/libraries do not exist in 23.10.  You will more than likely need to find a new screen recorder solution.  Additionally, I believe Python 2 is version 2.8 that *is* still available, though the vast majority of other Python 2 packages are not going to be available,

Comment: It's weird that it worked for the others on 20.04, assuming you're on 20.04, as the python2 packages available for 20.04 aren't "python" but "python2.7" with the version number in the name. Have you tried: `sudo apt install python2`? Regardless of if 2.7 is installed or not, `python2` is it's own package which may help to solve the dependency issue. Or for overkill `sudo apt install python2 python2.7`

Comment: I guess it should be noted that the python2 packages mentioned are only available on 20.04 and 22.04

Comment: Please be specific with details; you mention *upgraded* to *newest* version; so you're on Ubuntu 23.10 ?  (ie. the 2023-October or latest release).  It's helpful if you're specific; as packages are built for a specific release.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kazam has all the capabilities you're looking for — you can pause and select the area you want to record.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kazam
```

From my experience, I've had the least problems with Kazam for screen recording and it almost always just works.

from `apt-cache show kazam`:

> Description-en: screencast and screenshot application created with design in mind
> ￰ ￰ ￰Kazam provides a well designed and easy to use interface for capturing
> ￰ ￰ ￰screencasts and screenshots. It can record desktop video and multiple audio
> ￰ ￰ ￰streams simultaneously with control over audio levels and the screen region
> ￰ ￰ ￰being captured.